# Spring Boot Autowired Repository null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, netty

I am creating a Netty UDP server using the spring framework. I have 3 classes and 1 interface.

**UDPServer.java**

```
package com.example.nettyUDPserver;

import java.net.InetAddress;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import akka.actor.ActorRef;
import io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelOption;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelPipeline;
import io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioDatagramChannel;


public class UDPServer {
    private int port;
    ActorRef serverActor = null;

    public UDPServer(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    public void run() throws Exception {
        final NioEventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        try {
            final Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
            b.group(group)
                .channel(NioDatagramChannel.class)
                .option(ChannelOption.SO_BROADCAST, true)
                .handler(new ChannelInitializer<NioDatagramChannel>() {
                    @Override
                    public void initChannel(final NioDatagramChannel ch) throws Exception {
                        ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
                        p.addLast(new IncomingPacketHandler());
                    }
                });

            Integer pPort = port;
            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            //InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.53");
            System.out.println("Localhost address is: " + address.toString());
            b.bind(address, pPort).sync().channel().closeFuture().await();
        } finally {
            group.shutdownGracefully().sync();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int port = 6001;
        new UDPServer(port).run();
    }
}
```

**IncomingPacketHandler.java**

```
package com.example.nettyUDPserver;

import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.example.dao.SensorRepository;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler;
import io.netty.channel.socket.DatagramPacket;

@ComponentScan("com.example.dao")
public class IncomingPacketHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<DatagramPacket>  {

    @Autowired
    SensorRepository repo;

    IncomingPacketHandler(){

    }

    @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, DatagramPacket packet) throws Exception {
        final InetAddress srcAddr = packet.sender().getAddress();

        ByteBuf buffer = packet.content();
        packet.replace(buffer);
        int len = buffer.readableBytes();
        byte[] message = new byte[len];
        buffer.readBytes(message);
        String str = new String(message, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode actualObj = mapper.readTree(str);

        int id = actualObj.get("sensor_id").asInt();
        String status = actualObj.get("status").asText();

        System.out.println("==========================================================");
        System.out.println("Source address of datagram received: " + srcAddr.toString());
        System.out.println("String message received: " + str);
        show();
    }

    public void show() {
        System.out.println("In show function, we will perform our CRUD operations");
        System.out.println(repo);
//      try {
//          this.repo.findAll().forEach(x -> System.out.println(x));
//      } catch (NullPointerException e) {
//          e.printStackTrace();
//      }

    }

}
```

**Sensor.java**

```
package com.example.models;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Sensor {

    @Id
    private int sensor_id;
    private String status;
    private double batLev;

    public int getSensor_id() {
        return sensor_id;
    }

    public void setSensor_id(int sensor_id) {
        this.sensor_id = sensor_id;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public double getBatLev() {
        return batLev;
    }

    public void setBatLev(double batLev) {
        this.batLev = batLev;
    }


}
```

**SensorRepository.java**

```
package com.example.dao;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.example.models.Sensor;

@Repository
public interface SensorRepository extends CrudRepository<Sensor, Integer> {

}
```

I am running my server in the class `UDPServer.java` and I can successfully get and decode datagrams. The problem is with the `SensorRepository` in the `IncomingPacketHandler.java` class. I am using the `@Autowired` notation in the variable and I am using the `@Repository` annotation in the interface, but when I print the value of the autowired repository, it is null, so I cannot make SQL queries. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

Thank you for your answers guys, much appreciated. I am denoting the `IncomingPacketHandler` class as a component and I am autowiring it in the `UDPServer` class. When I run it I get this:

```
[nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] DEBUG io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline - Discarded inbound message DatagramPacket(/192.168.61.64:59905 => /192.168.61.64:6001, PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 38, cap: 2048)) that reached at the tail of the pipeline. Please check your pipeline configuration.
```

This is probably out of the scope of this question, but you maybe can show me tha direction. Thank you once again.

Comment: You need to setup `@SpringBootApplication` and `@ComponentScan` for `UDPServer` class, because Spring needs create handler, context and inject them into your class

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your class `IncomingPacketHandler` is not managed by Spring, but created by you personally:

```
ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
p.addLast(new IncomingPacketHandler());
```

As such, even if you add a million Spring annotations, they won't do anything. What you want instead is to have Spring create this handler, and pass the Spring-created handler as argument to `p.addLast`

Answer (score 1):

The `IncomingPacketHandler` class has been created manually and not by Spring and hence `bean` is not available.

Add `@Component` to `IncomingPacketHandler` class:

```
...

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class IncomingPacketHandler extends

...
```

And then in `UDPServer.java`:

```
...

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

@Component
public class UDPServer {

@Autowired
private IncomingPacketHandler incomingPacketHandler;
...
```